# Use PHP into JQuery Array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have used an example table from X-Editable, this uses an array in JQuery to populate a drop down options box. This is great but I want to use the database to feed the array.

This below is the code from the X-Editable demo

```
var jsStringFromPHP = "<?php echo json_encode($r); ?>";

$.mockjax({
url: 'myphppage.php',
response: function (settings) {
    this.responseText = jsStringFromPHP;
    log(settings, this);
}
});
```

This is what I've done to get the array from my database

```
<?php
require 'assets/functions/core/init.php';
$p = db::getInstance()->query('SELECT id as value, name as text FROM information', array());
    $r = $p->results();
    echo json_encode($r);
?>
```

How can I incorporate the php array into the jquery and replace the static list?

Comment: remove the `<pre>` tag, and use the result of your php output as a json object via ajax.

Comment: Thanks but after `this.responseText =` in the jquery how do I call it?

Comment: you receive your response json in settings argument of your ajax callback.

Comment: `this.responseText = {settings}` i guess

Comment: Sorry don't understand the {settings}, what does that represent, I'm trying to understand how I can call the php code to run within the jqUery

Comment: you should rename settings to data (because this is what is usually called). This will contain whatever PHP echoes.. Then you have to parse it and do some DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just encode your array to `JSON` using `json_encode` & return that in response. Then in `success` callback of ajax function, use that `JSON` string.

To know more about how to handle it, read it: [Load JSON Data Using jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122428/load-json-data-using-jquery-ajax)

Use in this way,

```
$.mockjax({
    url: "hello.php",
    proxy: 'sample.json',
    responseTime: 0,
    dataType: 'json'
});

$.ajax({
    url: "hello.php",
    dataType: 'json'

}).done(function (json_response) {

    var names = [];
    for (i in json_response.employees) {
        names.push(json_response.employees[i].firstName);
    }
    output = names.join("<br/>");
    $('#output_fake_json').html(output);

    $.mockjaxClear();
});
```

More details can be found here on plugin page: http://www.vikaskbh.com/jquery-fake-ajax-requests-for-ajax-testing-using-mockjax-plugin/

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look at that and amended my original post, I don't understand where I can call the actual php page from to run the echo of json_encode?

Comment: code & tutorial added in the last of my answer. This will help you.

Comment: @539 You are calling the php with the url in ajax (e.g `hello.php`)! Do some reading to get the concepts right :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had tried the php inside the url first, with it showing errors in the console log and then after much reading changed it to the /groups as that was how the X-Editable site had shown it. After changing it back, some reason it has worked.